# Textbox won't update in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textbox

I'm making a very simple JRPG battle system in AS3. I have a textbox called output that displays the battle events. The font is embedded (I've check a dozen times). It's white text on a black background. The initial text displays, but after that it won't update. I have the code set to trace what's going on, and that displays correctly. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Here's the code (obviously this isn't complete):

```
function BattleSystem():void
        {
            //add battle system event listeners
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,onKeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);

            //initialize battle
            this.gotoAndStop(2);
            battleStart = true;
            playerAtks = false;
            output.text = ""
            output.text = "A dangerous " + _enemyName + " threatens to attack! What will you do? 1. Attack 2. Spells 3. Items ";


            function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
                {           

                    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_1)
                    {
                        playerDmg = uint(_Str * ((Math.random() + 1)) - _enemyDef);
                    }
                }
            function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
            {
                if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_1)
                {
                    trace("You deal " + playerDmg + " damage to the " + _enemyName + "!")
                    output.text = "You deal " + playerDmg + " damage to the " + _enemyName + "!";
                }
            }
        }
```

For example, currently when I enter into battle, output displays "A dangerous Slime threatens to attack! What will you do? 1. Attack 2. Spells 3. Items". But when I hit 1, the output does not change.

Answer (score 0):

You have your event handlers encapsulated in the function, that's not right.

Try this :

```
function BattleSystem():void
{
     //add battle system event listeners
     stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,onKeyDown);
     stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);

     //initialize battle
     this.gotoAndStop(2);
     battleStart = true;
     playerAtks = false;
     output.text = ""
     output.text = "A dangerous " + _enemyName + " threatens to attack! What will you do? 1. Attack 2. Spells 3. Items ";

}

function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{           

      if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_1)
      {
          playerDmg = uint(_Str * ((Math.random() + 1)) - _enemyDef);
      }
}

function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMBER_1)
    {
         trace("You deal " + playerDmg + " damage to the " + _enemyName + "!")
         output.text = "You deal " + playerDmg + " damage to the " + _enemyName + "!";
     }
}
```